# How to retrieve from DB table having timestamp column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table which is having timestamp column as follows

```
ID            timeStamp    var1    var2    var3
1   05-09-2013 18:23:56     0       1       1
2   05-09-2013 18:23:57     0       0       1
3   05-09-2013 18:23:58     1       0       1
4   05-09-2013 18:23:59     1       0       1
```

I want to retrieve according to timestamp like timestamp>05-09-2013 18:23:56 and timestamp <05-09-2013 18:23:59

I am trying these ways

```
select * from test where timeStamp<'05-09-2013 18:23:59' and timeStamp>'05-09-2013 18:23:57'
```

Its giving null rows.I had tried using `between` keyword still not getting the desired result.

```
SELECT     *  FROM            test
WHERE        (timeStamp BETWEEN '05-09-2013 18:23:57' AND '05-09-2013 18:23:59')
```

May i know what wrong I am doing here?
here is the screen shot

[image]

This screenshot is without **where** clause
[image]

This screen shot shows table **DESCRIPTION**
[image]

Comment: how many rows does the query return?

Comment: Could you please create a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to show us a demo?

Comment: @AmitSingh Start date End Date?

Comment: This seems to work fine if your dates are correct. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64955/2 maybe try telling us what the exact dates are, as 05-09 can be easily confused with 09-05 based on regional/database settings

Comment: @astander while inserting I use getDate()

Comment: Show us a screen shot of the table without the where condition, so that we can see the date formats.

Comment: @astander please see the attached screenshot

Comment: Have you tried running the query with the where clause *where timeStamp<'2013-09-05 18:23:59' and timeStamp>'2013-009-05 18:23:57'*

Comment: yes I have just copied from fiddele that you have posted but still getting the same problem

Comment: @astander Do you know which database sqlfiddle use?I am asking because the query you posted works perfectly in fiddle but not in my sql server

Comment: This was using SQL Server 2012. Try to specify the month names, so that you can see which month it is in. So something like *where timeStamp<'05 Sep 2013 18:23:59' and timeStamp>'05 Sep 2013 18:23:57'* or *where timeStamp<'09 May 2013 18:23:59' and timeStamp>'09 May 2013 18:23:57'*

Comment: well When i insert in db it inserts 05-09-2013 18:23:56 but in fiddle it inserts in May, 09 2013 18:23:56+0000

Comment: @astander see this way is between '05-09-2013 18:23:57' and '05-09-2013 18:23:59' is not working.Is it possible to get according to id.I mean to say that input will be in time but while gettting it will get accroding to ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use appropriate datetime literals that don't break your queries. More and detailed explanations at **[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)**

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    test
WHERE   ( timeStamp BETWEEN '2013-09-05T18:23:57' AND '2013-09-05T18:23:59' ) ;
```

Also note that a timestamp with time part above `18:23:59.000`, like `'18:23:59.100'` will not be included in the results because the above condition is equivalent to:

```
WHERE   timeStamp >= '2013-09-05T18:23:57.000' 
  AND   timeStamp <= '2013-09-05T18:23:59.000'
```

So, you may want this instead:

```
SELECT  *  
FROM    test
WHERE   timeStamp >= '2013-09-05T18:23:57.000' 
  AND   timeStamp <  '2013-09-05T18:24:00.000'
```

The use of `BETWEEN` in date and datetime comparisons is not advised, for this reasons. See another blog post by @Aaron Bertrand: **[What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

Comment: what ever I do ,i get only null values,you can check the screenshot

Comment: You didn't try what I wrote. I see `>= '09-05-2013 ...` in that image. Please read again the code in this answer.

Comment: I apologize ,I made some mistake.Your code works perfectly well.Thanks